# WordPress - Excluding div container from next pagination page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have such a text container. He would like it to appear only on the first page of the blog's pagination.

```
<div class="column mcb-column mcb-item-c0belar2g one column_visual">
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
</div>
```

I have a text container generated by Muffin Page Builder in WordPress. He would like it to appear only on the first page of the blog's pagination. I tried to create a code like this:

```
if (1 == $ paged) {
your container code
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't know if I need to create a function to hide this container on the following pages of pagination?

[Here is a link to this blog page](https://www.controlling-systems.pl/blog-o-controllingu/)

I am trying to find information on the Internet, but so far I have not been able to find anything about it. Please help.

[Image of this container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92n49.png)